# Two column div layout, text aligned right

Tags: css, html

I'm looking for the best way to create a block of left-aligned text and a block of right aligned text inside a div.

[This is an image of what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX2SC.png)

I've thought about creating three `div`s with one in the middle acting as a buffer, but it doesn't seem to work. I'd need to hard code the length of the middle div, and this doesn't seem like the best approach

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
 <div style="float: left;">left aligned text</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 100%" > </div>
 <div style="float: left;">right aligned text </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "right aligned text", do you mean `text-align: right`, or simply left aligned text that is in the right side of the parent div?

Comment: to the right side of the parent div

Comment: Well, @Kau-Boy has it, if you simply remove `text-align: right` from his demo.

Comment: So he actually asked for a right aligned DIV and not a right aligned DIV AND right aligned text inside. Yes than simply remove the `text-align` but keep the `float: right` and the width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the "text-align" property on the second div?

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
 <div style="float: left;">left aligned text</div>
 <div style="float: right; text-align: right;">right aligned text </div> 
</div>
```

EDIT: You don't need a middle DIV for a spacing. You can simple use a percentage width for the two other DIVs and using float left and right you have a "buffer":

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 45%;">left aligned text</div>
 <div style="float: right; text-align: right; width: 45%;">right aligned text </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: will that push the "right aligned text" to the right side of the parent div?

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
 <div style="float:left">left aligned text</div>
 <div style="text-align: right;">right aligned text </div> 
</div>
```